# Powers of orthogonal matrices is closed

Tags: linear-algebra

This might be a basic question, nonetheless I cannot give a proof.

Given an orthogonal matrix $A$ with eigendecomposition $A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}$ with only non-real eigenvalues. Given also a diagonal real matrix $\Phi$ with $\Phi_{ii} = \Phi_{jj}$ if $\Lambda_{ii} = \overline{\Lambda_{jj}}$. The following matrix power is defined as $[\Lambda^\Phi]_{ii} := \Lambda_{ii}^{\Phi_{ii}}$.

Why is $Q \Lambda^\Phi Q^{-1}$ orthogonal? (Unitarity is simple, but why is it real?)

Comment: Have you tried what happens if $A=-I$ and $\Phi=\frac12I$?

Comment: @Joonas: Sorry, I just realized that I was quite loose on the restrictions. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex eigenvalues of a real matrix come in conjugate-complex pairs, with conjugate-complex pairs of eigenvectors. But the converse is true: If you associate to conjugate-complex pairs of eigenvectors any conjugate-complex pairs of eigenvalues, the result will be real because it is the sum of two terms which are conjugate-complex. You can take *any* diagonal matrix $\Psi$ with $\Psi_{ii} =\overline{\Psi_{jj}}$ if $\Lambda_{ii} = \overline{\Lambda_{jj}}$, and
$Q\Psi Q^{-1}$ will be orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess this is also true for any real matrix, right? Is there a short argument for this? Or textbook reference. Sorry, this is definitely no research level question.

Comment: @Sebastian, What do you mean, "any real matrix", for which matrix? Was my argument not short enough?

Comment: All fine. I was just asking whether the restriction on $Q$ matters, but I already realized that it does not. So that the fact is true for any paris of conjugate-complex pairs eigenvalues and eigenvectors. And also your answer was short enough. Thanks